# Implementation of abstract method

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class ShowFileStatus {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String uri = args[0];
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);

        Path file = new Path(args[0]);
        FileStatus stat = fs.getFileStatus(file);
        System.out.println(stat.getLen());
    }
}
```

`getFileStatus()` is an abstract method in `FileSystem` class and `FileSystem` class need to be extended to use the `getFileStatus()` method.. 
But in the above code I am able to use method without extending the `FileSystem` class. 
How ? I am not able to understand this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you acquired the instance of `FileSystem` class using static factory method provided in `FileSystem` class. It internally creates an instance of one of its own implementation. There are many implementation available of [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html).

```
public static FileSystem get(URI uri, Configuration conf) throws IOException
```

> Returns the FileSystem for this URI's scheme and authority. The scheme of the URI determines a configuration property name, fs.scheme.class whose value names the FileSystem class. The entire URI is passed to the FileSystem instance's initialize method.

Now essentially, you will be calling `getFileStatus` method of one the provided implementation.

Comment: But how could we use getFileStatus()  method without defining it

Comment: You are missing the dynamic nature of the Java. The actual method invocation is decided on run time depending on the reference. This is called polymorshism. Looks like, you are considering only static (compile time) binding of method where as actual invocation is decided on run time.